# Pandas DataFrame: reorder the rows so that consecutive rows belong to same or adjacent "class"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to reorder the rows of my DataFrame according to a particular policy. I am gonna explain it.
In the dataset there is a column, named "class" which is an integer number {0,1,2,3}.
I want to randomly reorder the rows of my dataframe so that consecutive rows belong to the same or adjacent classes.

Let me make an example: if the second row belongs to class 1 ( `df.[1]["class"]==1`  ), the first and third rows must belong to class 0, 1 or 2.

Example:

```
data = [['x', 0], ['y', 0], ['w', 2], ['z', 1], ['k', 2], ['j', 3]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'Class'])
```

I'm looking for a reordering function so that the output is something like:

```
col1    Class
 x        0
 y        0
 z        1
 w        2
 j        3
 k        2
```

or:

```
col1    Class
 x        0
 y        0
 z        1
 w        2
 k        2
 j        3
```

Comment: Just sort the rows according to the *class* column...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried so far. It sounds like you want the `sort_values()` method, but it's hard to know how to help without more specific information

Comment: @G.Anderson I have edited the topic

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general example from [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) of using `sort_values` by a specific column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
})
```

Output

```
    col1 col2 col3
0   A    2    0
1   A    1    1
2   B    9    9
3   NaN  8    4
4   D    7    2
5   C    4    3
```

Sort by column name

```
df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
    col1 col2 col3
0   A    2    0
1   A    1    1
2   B    9    9
5   C    4    3
4   D    7    2
3   NaN  8    4
```

Comment: This is a decent answer, but could be improved by linking to the documentation, then showing how you would apply the function to the data in the question to produce the expected output, rather than just copying from the documentation directly